# JPA Native Query for Entity with Inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, orm, jpa

I have an entity class and a subclass based on that entity:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class A
```

and

```
@Entity
public class B extends A
```

I need to issue a native query that uses a stored procedure on the base class (A) only.  If I attempt it as follows:

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("select * from A a where procedure(f)",A.class).getResultList()
```

I get an error regarding "The column clazz_ was not found in the ResultSet".  I assume that the JPA provider adds this column in order to discriminate between the base class and the extended class.  I can work around this problem by explicitly adding the clazz column and all of the fields from the subclass:

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("select *,1 as clazz_,null as prop1,null as prop2 from A a where procedure(f)",A.class).getResultList()
```

where "prop1" and "prop2" are properties of the subclass B.  However, this seems like an unnecessary hack and is prone to maintenance problems if the subclass B changes.

My question is: How can I query using a stored procedure on an entity that has inheritance defined on it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you've probably seen, the Hibernate team hasn't put a lot of work into defining how you do this.. the documentation simply states:

> 16.1.6. Handling inheritance
>
> Native SQL queries which query for
>   entities that are mapped as part of an
>   inheritance must include all
>   properties for the baseclass and all
>   its subclasses.

So if you want to use Native queries it looks like you're stuck doing something like this.  Regarding the concern about the subclass B changing, perhaps a slightly less onerous way of implementing this would be to try using LEFT OUTER JOIN syntax on the shared ID property:

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("select a.*, b*, 1 as clazz_, from A a LEFT OUTER JOIN B b on id = a.id where procedure(f)",A.class).getResultList()
```

That way you'll always get all of the properties from B if you add or remove some.

Comment: So, I had thought of this, but the problem is that when Hibernate attempts to inflate the object from the ResultSet row, it finds two id columns, one of which is null.  I suppose I can add an additional where clause the filters out 'b.id is null'.

Comment: The question is: When we write it this way, would we always get instances of class B?

Answer (score 0):

You need to distinguish instances of A from instances of B, using a discriminator.
Use one of the following annotations:

```
@DiscriminatorValue
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/DiscriminatorValue.html

```
@DiscriminatorColumn
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/DiscriminatorColumn.html

```
@DiscriminatorFormula
```

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#d0e1168