# How does hibernate distinguish entity types in native query in case of inheritance. What is the real meaning of clazz_ column?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, inheritance

I have a hierarchy of entities:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
class A {
  @Id
  private Long id;
}

@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
class B extends A {
}
```

And a query which retrieves A entities when record in table B does not exist and B entities in other case. I created JPQL query and it worked perfectly, but query had too high cost at the database side. So I decided to create native query and map it to entities. I was wondering how to let Hibernate know which entity should be returned and I found some solution:

[JPA Native Query for Entity with Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140992/jpa-native-query-for-entity-with-inheritance)

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("select a.*, b*, 1 as clazz_, from A a LEFT OUTER JOIN B b on id = a.id where procedure(f)",A.class).getResultList()
```

It looks like there is a special artificial column to distinguish between types. My JPQL query when translated to SQL also had this column. In above example this column has always value of `1`. In my JPQL query it rather looked like:

```
case when cim.id is not null then 1 when ci.id is not null then 0 end as clazz_
```

I can just rewrite this into my native query, but how can I be sure that mapping of values `0` and `1` to given types won't change next time? What if I add another class extending A?

Answer (score 0):

The [JoinedSubclassEntityPersister](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/persister/entity/JoinedSubclassEntityPersister.java) defines an `IMPLICIT_DISCRIMINATOR_ALIAS` property:

```
private static final String IMPLICIT_DISCRIMINATOR_ALIAS = "clazz_";
```

Which is used when you don't specify an explicit discriminator value:

```
explicitDiscriminatorColumnName = null;
discriminatorAlias = IMPLICIT_DISCRIMINATOR_ALIAS;
discriminatorType = StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER;
try {
    discriminatorValue = persistentClass.getSubclassId();
    discriminatorSQLString = discriminatorValue.toString();
}
catch ( Exception e ) {
    throw new MappingException( "Could not format discriminator value to SQL string", e );
}
```

The `0` and `1` values come from `persistentClass.getSubclassId();` which is assigned by Hibernate at runtime:

```
public Subclass(PersistentClass superclass) {
    this.superclass = superclass;
    this.subclassId = superclass.nextSubclassId();
}
```

the RootClass default id being `0`:

```
@Override
public int getSubclassId() {
    return 0;
}
```

Because the identifiers are assigned at runtime, it's unclear what will happen if a new subclass is added and it's being loaded prior to some already existing ones, so you are better off setting this value explicitly and bypass the implicit subclass ids:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "discriminator", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
class A {
  @Id
  private Long id;
}

@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
@DiscriminatorValue(value = 1)
class B extends A {
}
```

or even better, specify a `STRING` discriminator:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "discriminator", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "A")
class A {
  @Id
  private Long id;
}

@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "B")
class B extends A {
}
```