# Is it possible use one repository for selecting subclasses in difference tables?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I want use one repository for selecting from difference tables entities.
I use Spring Data JPA and have own query method:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM ?=1 WHERE ref_id=?2", nativeQuery = true)
BaseEntity findByRefId(String tableName, Long refId);
```

First question is it possible somehow pass table name? Because for now I'm harcoding table names.

Next I have two subclasses EntityOne and EntityTwo. Their fields(columns) are the same as BaseEntity but they must be in different tables.

```
@MappedSuperclass // or @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS) and @Entity    
BaseEntity
        |
        @Entity
        EntityOne
        |
        @Entity
        EntityTwo
```

I've tried use @MappedSuperclass annotation for BaseEntity. But it doesn't work, I got exception that BaseEntity must be annotated as @Entity. 
Also I've tried annotated BaseEntity as @Entity and @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS) but I got SQLException: Column 'clazz_' not found. I even don't have that column.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? That's not the concept of Spring Data: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.8.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts

Comment: For saving it works good. But I need select using own query.

Comment: And why? I mean having a repository per Entity is a good concept

Comment: You can do this if `BaseEntity` is an Entity rather than a MappedSuperclass. The error you get when you tried this is because you are using a native query. See futher: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140992/jpa-native-query-for-entity-with-inheritance

Answer (score 0):

From spring-docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RC1/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html

Look at Example 2.12

You can use SpEL to do so:

```
  @Query("select t from #{#entityName} t where t.attribute = ?1")
  List<T> findAllByAttribute(String attribute);
```