# Spring boot @query nativequery not working

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

So, the following query I've executed on database and it worked perfectly ...

```
SELECT c.* FROM category c
LEFT JOIN category_parent cp on c.id = cp.id_category
WHERE c.show_on_trending = 1
```

Then I tried with @Query annotation on Spring Boot, didn't work

> java.sql.SQLException: Column 'clazz_' not found.

no ideia why... Here's the entity

```
@Entity(name = "category")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @JsonView(CustomJsonView.Test.class)
    private int id;
    @JsonView(CustomJsonView.Test.class)
    private String categoryTitle;
    private String categoryDescription;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "Category_Parent",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_category", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_category_parent")
    )
    private List<Category> parentCategory;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "Category_Parent",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_category_parent", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_category")
    )
    @JsonView(CustomJsonView.Test.class)
    private List<Category> subCategory;

    private String imageUrl;

    private boolean showOnNavbar;

    private boolean showOnTrending;

//getters & setters
}
```

**----- EDIT -----**

```
@Query(
    value = "select c.* from category as c " +
            "left join category_parent as cp on c.id = cp.id_category " +
            "where c.show_on_trending = 1",
    nativeQuery = true
)
List<Category> getAllCategories();
```

Here's the thing, that query works perfectly when I execute it directly in database, and the weird part is that the query like it is does not work on spring boot (the error occurs when app invokes the query) but if I delete the condition `"where c.show_on_trending = 1"` it works....

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        c.id 
    from
        category as c 
    left join
        category_parent as cp 
            on c.id = cp.id_category 
2021-05-21 19:31:23.275  WARN 1508 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S0022
2021-05-21 19:31:23.275 ERROR 1508 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column 'clazz_' not found.
2021-05-21 19:31:23.289 ERROR 1508 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query; SQL [select c.id from category as c left join category_parent as cp on c.id = cp.id_category ]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query] with root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Column 'clazz_' not found.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:575) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:837) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getInt(HikariProxyResultSet.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.IntegerTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:249) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getInstanceClass(Loader.java:1930) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1725) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1622) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:740) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowsFromResultSet(Loader.java:1039) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:990) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:959) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2849) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2831) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2663) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2658) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2141) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1172) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:176) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1593) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:406) ~[spring-orm-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy103.getResultList(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:126) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:155) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:143) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:131) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy94.getAllCategories(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.ecommerce.quoide9.category.CategoryService.test(CategoryService.java:45) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.ecommerce.quoide9.category.CategoryController.test(CategoryController.java:50) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) ~[na:na]
```

**------------- FINAL EDIT -------------**

Basically, turns out its an Hibernate issue, I have to add `1 as clazz_` in the query like that

```
SELECT c.*, 1 as clazz_ FROM category c
LEFT JOIN category_parent cp on c.id = cp.id_category
WHERE c.show_on_trending = 1
```

credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2149829/13946707

Comment: can you share the @Query? did the exception happen when the app invoked your @Query or at application startup?

Comment: Hello, thx for your comment, I just edited that question with the required information. The exception occurs when the app invokes the @Query.

Comment: please share a full error stack

Comment: it seems (according to the shared code) like the `Category` entity doesn't have a mapped property for a `show_on_trending` column

Comment: was my bad, didn't copy them to the post.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to **FINAL EDIT**

It's not an issue, but documented behaviour. The root cause is in the inheritance strategy - using `JOINED` makes `Hibernate` generate extra sql code to provide ability distinguish among polymorphic classes. And it would be similarly like this:

```
select 
  entity0_.Id as Id27_,   
  [category fields]
  case 
    when entity0_1_.EntityId is not null then 1     
    when entity0_.Id is not null then 0 
  end as clazz_ 
from 
  category entity0_ 
  left outer join category_parent entity0_1_ on entity0_.Id=entity0_1_.EntityId
```

So anyway it has some sence from the point of view of `Hibernate` despite the obvious ugliness. Briefly you can just leave it like you showed above or add this `case` part into the native query. [Here is](https://www.methodicmadness.com/2009/01/nhibernate-what-is-heck-clazz.html) a nice research article about the issue

Comment: Thanks, does it behave the same way regardless the inheritance strategy?

Comment: well, I didn't explore it, but obvious that `SINGLE_TABLE` which is the default strategy, wouldn't lead to arising such a code. On the other hand, `TABLE_PER_CLASS` should make `Hibernate` similar to `JOINED` behaviour coz it allows associations and polymorphic queries

Answer (score 0):

Please check example

```
 @Query("SELECT c FROM category c " +
            "LEFT JOIN category_parent cp ON c.id = cp.id_category " +
            "WHERE c.show_on_trending = 1",
)
```

Comment: Hi, thx for the comment, I tried, still didn't work... It works without the condition, that makes no sense.

Comment: now it give me another error "no c column found in field list"

Comment: no mate, still not work, I found the fix however... editing my post

Comment: If there is a colum in such table, why didn't you write that colum name in your entity? (colum clazz_  name)

Comment: there isn't, it is just an Hibernate issue, check the link that I posted when I edited that question, he explains it.